# NoMethodError in SessionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org, nomethoderror

I've been following along with Michael Hartl's Tutorial, and for those who are familiar with it, I'm on Lesson 10 - Updating Users.

So far I've built an app that should allow users to sign up, sign in, and sign out. My app allows users to sign up, but when trying to sign in I get the following error:

## NoMethodError in SessionsController#create

```
undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: /Users/user/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app1

app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

## Request

#### Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"/SEaqnrMf5X0pd4FVWbu8uWVAjTNw4LPKiXg+8Hl0PQ=",
"session"=>{"email"=>"Anthonypane@example.com",
"password"=>"[FILTERED]"},
"commit"=>"Sign in"}
```

Here are my Session_Controller Contents:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def new
@title = "Sign in"
end

def create
user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                        params[:session][:password])
if user.nil?
flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
@title - "Sign In"
render 'new'
else
sign_in user
redirect_to user
end
end   

def destroy
 sign_out
 redirect_to root_path
end
end
```

Users_Controller contents

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @title = @user.name 
 end

def new
@user = User.new
@title = "Sign up"
end

def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
sign_in @user
redirect_to @user, :flash =>  {:success => "Welcome to the Fun House!"}
else
@title = "Sign up"
 render 'new'
end
end
end
```

Sessions_helper contents

```
module SessionsHelper

 def sign_in(user)
cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
current_user = user
end

def current_user=(user)
@current_user = user
end

def current_user
 @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end

def signed_in?
 !current_user.nil? 
end

def sign_out
 cookies.delete(:remember_token)
 self.current_user = nil
end 

private

def user_from_remember_token
 User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
end

def remember_token
 cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
end

end
```

And Lastly Users_helper contents:

```
module UsersHelper
def gravatar_for(user, options = { :size => 50})
gravatar_image_tag(user.email.downcase, :alt => user.name, 
                                        :class => 'gravatar',
                                        :gravatar => options)
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

:-) Problem solved thanks to Taryn East.

```
def has_password?(submitted_password)
  encrypted_password == encrypted(submitted_password)
end
```

should be

```
def has_password?(submitted_password)
  encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, like the exception says, your line `@title - "Sign In"`: it should be
`@title = "Sign In"`.

However, I would say a bigger issue is why you're doing the [Rails 3.0 version](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.0) of the tutorial now when the [Rails 3.2 version](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) is the latest.  It's definitely worth switching up.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've just made the '@title = "Sign In"' change, but I am still getting the same error when trying to sign-in:  NoMethodError in SessionsController#create. I am using the LiveLessons version so it isn't updated as frequently as the text version. Any other ideas on how we can go about troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: Without more context and information, it's difficult to figure out why you're getting this error, but since you're on Chapter 10, you should be used to seeing this *kind* of error, and it's in your best interest to take a crack at solving what the problem is first.  So, try and solve it, and then if you find you can't, put up another question on StackOverflow with the relevant information.

Comment: Actually, re-thinking this, if you're getting `NoMethodError in SessionsController#create` when signing in (which I assume means it failed on `sign_in`, which is in the `SessionsHelper`), have you made sure to `include SessionsHelper` in your `ApplicationController`?